# Не понятно работает websocket (wss). Иногда работает иногда нет. В чем проблема?

Tags: node.js, websocket, https, ssl

Есть сервер node js и есть клиент html5(js). Общение сделал через websocket. Все работает на ура!
Позже понадобилось общение через wss.
Взял у comodo 3-х месячный бесплатный сертификат. не самоподписный, есть цепочка на 3 верхних сертификата, да и проверка сайта на сертификат говорит что все хорошо.
Установил на сервере в nginx
скармливаю сертификат в node js:

```
   var httpsOptions = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('/domain.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('/domain.crt'),
   requestCert: true,
   rejectUnauthorized: false,
   };
```

Пробую подключиться клиентом....
и дальше творятся чудеса, браузеры вообще по разному работают:
Как я понял нужно чтоб прошло рукопожатие.
Сначала вообще ничего не работало.

Далее нашел совет-трюк: перейти по ссылке wss://domain.ru:8082 заменив wss на https. И это сработало! Но не во всех браузерах. в ИЕ не сработало.
Собственно это тоже не вариант... обычный пользователь так делать не будет.
Собственно если этого не делать, то так ничего и не работает.
в хроме это выглядит так:

> Websocket connection to wss://domain.ru:8082 failed: Websocket opening
>   handshake was canceled. (opcode-1)

До nodejs скорее всего вообще ничего не доходит т.к. ошибки подключения нет. 
Да и с трюком nodejs вполне себе начинает отвечать, поэтому думаю дело не в нем.
Информации по этой проблеме очень мало, а на русском так вообще не нашел. 
Хотелось бы понять куда рыть? как дебажить?

UPD: Проверил логи nginx и тоже ничего. Ощущение что браузер ваще ничего никуда не отсылает, ибо не доверяет. Правильное ли предположение?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такое обсуждалось [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate#comment33762412_15076602), мол Хром и IE не доверяет self-signed SSL сертификату. Так что, либо купить сертификат, либо ручками добавить в список доверенных сертификатов в браузере.

Ну и да, небольшая рекомендация: лучше делать offload ssl на стороне nginx, а потом проксировать уже дешифрованный трафик в nodejs.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только я как раз выше написал что сертификат хоть и бесплатный на 3 месяца но не самоподписный, т.е. у него есть цепочка сертификатов. Сайты проверяющие корректность сайтов на сертификаты говорят что все ок у меня. А задача дешифровать трафик  ДО nodejs я думаю не относится к этой проблеме..тем не менее было бы интересно знать как это сделать:) Да и шифрованый трафик который доходит до nodejs вполне там расшифровывается и всё работает...

Comment: у меня всё прекрасно работает с самоподписанными сертификатами. Возможно дело в серверной части, которая не правлиьно с этими сертификатами обращается. сервер на java. единственная проблема - ручками добавлять... не все юзера на это способны

Answer (score 0):

нашел проблему всё дело в этом

```
var httpsOptions = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('/domain.key'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('/domain.crt'),
   requestCert: true,
   rejectUnauthorized: false,
   };
```

Вот это:

```
   requestCert: true,
   rejectUnauthorized: false,
```

лишнее. Где то в интернете нашел пример с этими параметрами, оказывается проблема именно в них.

Comment: очень похоже, судя по вашему вопросу и комментариям в других ответах, что вы таки дешифруете трафик на стороне Nginx, и когда  requestCert: true стоит, то до node уже не доходит шифрованный трафик и соответственно она отпинывала.